# Converting org.w3c.dom.Document to org.apache.html.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl

Tags: java, html, apache, parsing, document

Is there anyway to convert an instance of org.w3c.dom.Document to org.apache.html.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl.

I need to parse the images inside the Document and HTMLDocumentImpl has a method for extracting the images.

I've tried several methods like typecasting, and importNode but it doesn't work.

Comment: I had a look at the both APIs. It says org.apache.html.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl implements org.w3c.dom.Document.

Comment: I'm already aware of this. Is there any way to convert Document to HTMLDocumentImpl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you tried casting, I'll assume that the `Document` instance you have is not a `org.apache.html.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl`. Two things that might be worth a shot:

1) The `getImages()` method is in fact defined on the interface `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDocument`, which is more likely to be implemented by whatever type of Dom document you have. Thus, you should be able to do something like:

```
if (doc instanceof HTMLDocument) {
    images = ((HTMLDocument) doc).getImages();
}
```

2) If that doesn't work, the [`getImages()`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/w3c/dom/html/HTMLDocument.html#getImages()) method is really not going to do anything much fancier than:

```
images = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
```